# Snapshot tests className with emotion/styled

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, emotion

Using react, jest, react-testing-library, emotion

Everytime I update a component the className in my snapshot tests updates because of how emotion/styled uses hash for classNames.

[image]

This keeps breaking my snapshot tests. Is it possible to make the classNames more static for testing?

I found this https://emotion.sh/docs/testing but it kinda does the opposite of what I want with adding the css to the snapshot tests..

Comment: Adding `@emotion/jest` will make your classnames more predictable (for example `emotion-1` instead of `css-10bechu`). Follow the instructions here: https://emotion.sh/docs/@emotion/jest. Like you saw, it will also add the styles to your snapshots, which you may or may not want depending on what you are testing.